# Like url point to page tab

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I have a FB app installed as a page tab. The only way the site I am working on is intended to be viewed is within the tab. The site has "entries" , I want to be able to like each entry individually, point to my pagetab and include the entry id as app_data in the query string.

When the landing page receives the post from the page tab I will check check the value of app_data and, if necessary, redirect to the appropriate details page.

So what I tried is when outputting the entries I use the like button like so:

```
<fb:like  layout="button_count" href="<%= this.GetDetailsUrl() %>"></fb:like>
```

GetDetailsUrl simply takes the url of my app and appends the entry id as app_data, something like this:

```
protected string GetDetailsUrl()
{
    return "http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_myappid?app_data=" + entry.EntryId.ToString(); 
}
```

Now, what is happening is the like button seems to only point to `http://www.facebook.com/mypage` , this happens when the like button is clicked and I can see that the like counter for each entry seems to point to the same place, they all have the same count.

Is there a way for me to have a like point to a page tab as I am trying to do? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

**edit:** After CBroe's suggestions I am using the following on my details page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Entry Title"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myredirect.com?id=entry_id"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite/entryimage.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://www.mysite.com"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Entry Description"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to have a like point to a page tab as I am trying to do?

You can not like page tabs, only the fan page itself can receive a like.

What you could do, is set up your entries as Open Graph objects – and then have those liked individually.

And when a user visits your OG URLs, you redirect them to your page tab from there, via JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. By setting up entries as Open Graph objects do you mean adding og meta tags to the details page?

Comment: Yes, and have them linked/liked “stand-alone” – and then redirect to displaying the entry inside of your page tab.

Comment: Thanks again. Ok, forgive me if I am a little slow. Right now I am adding an open graph object to my application. The "Like" action seems to only work with "object". Is this a step I have to take in order for the og tags to be parsed correctly?

Comment: No, you don’t need to add any Open Graph features to your app itself. Just have your entry pages fitted with the appropriate Open Graph meta tags, that’s enough to like them “the normal way”.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I've modified my original post to include the meta tags I am going to use on my details page. I used the type "article" as I thought it would be the most appropriate for what I am using it for. Could you take a peek and tell me if it looks good to you? Thanks again!